# How to get rid of Singleton variables errors?

Tags: prolog

I'm supposed to implement a little prolog program out of the Monty Python movie where the people are arguing whether a woman is a witch. Based on what the say, witches are burned, but wood is also burned, and wood floats, but ducks also float, so, if someone weighs the same as a duck, she's made of wood, therefore, she's a witch.

Based on that, I've come up with this:

```
witch(X) :- burns(X), female(X).
burns(X) :- wooden(X).
wooden(X) :- floats(X).
floats(X) :- sameWeight(duck, X).

female(X). 
sameweight(duck, X).
```

But when I want to check if X is a witch, by trying witch(X). It actually prints "true", confiming the woman is a witch, but I also get a `Singleton variables: [X]` error message. So clearly I have a bug somewhere and I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *warnings*. It specifies that you use a variable *once* in clause. This is the case for `X` in:

```
female(X). 
sameweight(duck, X).
```

Now this is rather "odd". Variables are typically used for passing values from head to body, or between two predicate calls in the body. But here you only use `X` once.

In Prolog one uses an *underscore* (`_`) if you "do not care" about the value. The underscore is an "anonymous variable": if you use two underscores in the same clause, those are two *different* variables.

So you can fix it like:

```
female(_). 
sameweight(duck, _).
```

Note that now you have written that *everything* is a `female`, and that everything has the same weight as a `duck`.

Comment: I saw an implementation where : female(girl). And sameWeight(duck, girl). Whats the logic behind that? I mean, why does that work?

Comment: With `girl` you specify that `girl` is a female. Here you specify that *everything* is a `female`, so `X` remains a free variable, and you predicate will succeed with *all* values.

Comment: @JorgePadilla `X` is a variable. `girl`, `duck` are not variables but atoms (specific constant values, if you will).